# Декодирование base64/UTF-16LE на Си

Tags: c, шифрование, base64, decode

Моя проблема заключается в попытке декодирования строки с кодировкой utf-16LE которая была зашифрована в base64. Результат такого декодирования всегда первый символ.
При этом если попробовать декодировать строку в utf-8/ascii/windows1252, то результат корректный.

Стандартный код из интернета:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    
    b64_decode_string("SABlAGwAbABvAA==");
    
    return 0;
}


char base64decode_lut[] = {
 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64 };
 

void base64decode(char *src, char *dest, int len)

{
 int i=0, slen=strlen(src);
 for(i=0;i<slen&&i<len;i+=4,src+=4)
 { 
 char c1=base64decode_lut[*src], c2=base64decode_lut[*(src+1)], c3=base64decode_lut[*(src+2)], c4=base64decode_lut[*(src+3)];

 *(dest++)=(c1&0x3F)<<0x2|(c2&0x30)>>0x4;
 *(dest++)=(c3!=64)?((c2&0xF)<<0x4|(c3&0x3C)>>0x2):'\0';
 *(dest++)=(c4!=64)?((c3&0x3)<<0x6|c4&0x3F):'\0';
 }
 *dest='\0'; // Append terminator
}
 
 
int b64_decode_string(char *source)

{
 int dest_size;
 int res;
 char *dest;
 dest_size = strlen(source);
 dest = (char *)malloc(dest_size);

 memset(dest,0,dest_size);
 base64decode(source, dest, dest_size);
 printf("Decode: %s", dest);

}
```

Comment: Логично, ведь utf-16 строка содержит в себе нулевые байты, а printf выводит строку только до нулевого байта, то есть на первом символе `H`, который `48 00`, и останавливается

Comment: @andreymal
К сожалению я очень плохо знаком с си, нагуглил ещё один метод вывода "puts" и результат тот же. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать как лучше вывести или проверить строку, что она правда декодируется?

Comment: `puts` не метод, а функция

Comment: Вам надо теперь вызвать функцию _iconv()_, чтобы преобразовать в UTF-8, тогда и выводите.

Comment: И ещё, зовите _calloc()_ вместо _malloc()_ + _memset()_, всегда проверяйте возвращаемые значения на ошибки.

Comment: @andriy, я думаю что проблема не с выводом. Т.к если дебажить то в результирующей строке dest хранится 1 символ.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, что вы там отлаживали и как проверяли, но код рабочий.
[Здесь с моими правками](https://pastebin.com/WSmDKLzN), конкретно то, что вам я пытался объяснить ниже:

```c
handle = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
if (handle < 0)
    perror("Can't open translation");

iconv(handle, &dest, &dest_size, &utf, &utf_size);

iconv_close(handle);

printf("Decode (UTF-8): %s\n", u);
```

И вот вывод работы программы:

```
% ./b64
0: 48
1: 0
2: 65
...

Decode: H
Decode (UTF-8): Hello
```